# Make the alias behavior permanent

Tags: osx

I create an alias behavior

```
    alias chrome="open -a 'Google Chrome'"
    chrome foo.html
```

Nevertheless, It refuses to work when I restart the terminal.

```
    $ chrome foo.html
    -bash: chrome: command not found
```

As a solution, I place the command to `~/.bash_profile`

```
    # Add to ~/.bash_profile
    # shortcut for chrome
    alias chrome="open -a 'Google Chrome'"
```

Again, it report similar error

```
    $ chrome foo.html
    -bash: chrome: command not found
```

How to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your alias definitions in a file, and make sure that file is sourced by your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.bashrc`.  e.g. add the following to one of those files:

```
[ -e ~/.bash-aliases ] && . ~/.bash-aliases
```

This will load the saved aliases into the shell whenever you login or start a new shell.

The following two aliases useful:

```
alias loadalias='source ~/.bash-aliases'
alias savealias='alias >~/.bash-aliases'
```

Enter the two aliases above and then run `savealias`.

`savealias` does exactly what the name implies - it saves the current shell's alias definitions to the `~/.bash-aliases` file.  It is important to note that it completely overwrites the existing file - be careful when using it if any aliases have been changed, or deleted with `unalias`.

`loadalias` is useful for loading the current `.bash-aliases` into you current shell.  Typical usage is to create or modify an alias in one terminal shell, save it with `savealias`, and then run `loadalias` in any other terminals you might have open.

---

There are probably lots of ways to improve alias management, but this is simple and very easy to set up on new systems.  I've been using it since the early 1990s and haven't needed anything more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Your alias should go in `.profile`.

Comment: Note that `bash` reads the `.profile` file _only_ if there is no `.bash_profile` file. This is not special for `bash` on macOS.

Comment: I don't know about his environment but when I tested it with mine, it read the alias when I put it in `.profile` despite `.bash_profile` existing.

Comment: Unless aliases work differently on OSX, the question seems fine here

Comment: The way that the environment is read in MacOS is usually different by default but that can be true of any Linux distro as well so you do make a good point. I'll edit that out.